# I cant add an integer as a variable in codeigniter from the cli

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

i have a very basic piece of code here:

```
public function output($start_date) 
{   
    echo $start_date;
}
```

This function currently resides in the welcome controller.  I am calling this function from the cli of the same  server, with the same user, with all the permissions set correctly.

If i call this function with an 'x', I get a proper result.  ex:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /home/website/html/php.ini /home/website/html/index.php welcome output 'x'
x
```

If I call this function with an integer, I get no result.  ex:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /home/website/html/php.ini /home/website/html/index.php welcome output '1'
```

I am losing my mind with this and im sure it is going to be something dumb.  I have changed the controller it resides in, I have changed the variable name, the function name, used double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, I have removed the '-c /home/website/html/php.ini'.  No matter what I do I cannot get an integer to display.   I can get a big long string,  I can put an alpha numeric character in front of an integer and it will display.  I just cant get an integer to output. Any ideas?  I am willing to try pretty much anything.

Comment: We could maybe benefit from seeing the way you are getting arguments/parameters in your script. Other than that, from what I can see in test inputs you provided, in the first case when you are saying everything displays properly, there is `'x' x` and x is displayed, which could imply that you are actually displaying the second argument/parameter.